# Ignore parent element using ngDraggable

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, drag-and-drop

I am using ngDraggable in an user case that consists of a div inside a div and both of them are draggable.

I want to reorder child elements and parents as well.

However, when I try to move the child, the parent is moved too.

Here is a plunkr that shows the issue:

http://plnkr.co/edit/xhLgXW0hPxLucQiKt6Q1?p=preview

```
<div ng-drag="true" class="red-box">
     <div ng-drag="true" class="blue-box">
     </div>
</div>
```

Try to move the blue box and the red will be dragged around together.

Someone knows how to move only the blue box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `ng-drag` is not meant to be nested. You can play with CSS to achieve the same appearance and get the expected behavior.

I have un-nested the divs (drag handles) and positioned them absolutely (the easiest solution for the example you gave).

http://plnkr.co/edit/cQ3aUmhvIoK58b88UpRv?p=preview

---

Another solution that does not use the PR suggested by OP is to add `ng-mousedown="$event.stopPropagation()"` to the child element, i.e.:

```
<div ng-drag="true" class="red-box">
 <div ng-drag="true" class="blue-box" ng-mousedown="$event.stopPropagation()"></div>
</div>
```

It prevents the parent element from receiving the mouse-down event, which starts the dragging.

http://plnkr.co/edit/onwCzYy4mtI8pz1mSoNV?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In fact the result is not what I was expecting because I would like to see the red box taking the blue box when moving. In my real case, the red box is a <li> and I take the child <ul> when dragged. I think it is not good to see the child staying when the parent move and then the child apperas out of the nowhere in the destination.

Comment: I found a workaround on ngDraggable github. Check my answer. Thank you again.

Comment: @rcorreia, please have a look at yet another solution in my answer.

Comment: nice one! I forked the code to use on bower. This approach is quite better.

Answer (score 1):

Analysing the issues on ngDraggable github I found one PR that did trick:

https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/ngDraggable/pull/183/files

Add the line `evt.stopImmediatePropagation()` after `if(! _dragEnabled)return` and voilà.

Plunker after the change

http://plnkr.co/edit/jbZ7DqzUsfchAG3k0qmY?p=preview